# Alternatives to returning NULL

Tags: java, design-patterns, null, return-value

```
   /**
     * Returns the foo with the matching id in this list
     * 
     * @param id the id of the foo to return
     * @return the foo with the matching id in this list
     */
    public Foo getFoo(int id)
    {
        for (Foo foo : list)
        {
            if (foo.getID() == id)
            {
                return foo;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Instead of returning `null` when `foo` is not found, should I `throw` an `exception`? Does it matter, and is there a "best practices" idiom on the subject? By the way, I know my example is a bit contrived, but I hope you get the idea...

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Changed code to get `Foo` based on *id* to better illustrate a real-world scenario.

Comment: There's a comment somewhere about a language designer saying he wished he'd never introduced the null value. I can't remember what his reasons were though.

Comment: @James P: That was CAR Hoare, here's a quote: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3186

Comment: You can use NULL OBJECT PATTERN. Check if that addresses your requirement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern  
Warning...  
This pattern should be used carefully as it can make errors/bugs appear as normal program execution.[5]

Comment: Wishing to not have implemented `null` sounds like a gun manufacturer wishing he hadn't designed a handgun after so many people have shot themselves in the foot...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Returning `null` is not only more simple to handle, performs better too. The exceptions must be used to handle *exceptional* cases.

Comment: This is an important point. If you don't know beforehand if it contains Foo, then null is usually better. If you always expect Foo to be in the list, then an exception might be more appropriate.

Comment: I disagree. Returning and checking from nulls is generally a smell.  The null object pattern can help nicely.

Comment: Reminds me of one of the Effective Java items: Avoid Null when possible ( http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=7EE954B4960C1D08A5C839EB018D24EE?Id=134 )

Comment: Yes, It must be avoided... But the @mre's question refers to what choose between return null or throw an exception. Other effective java item (and efficient too) is not abuse the exception throwing because they have a computational cost. You must balance desing and performance to deliver a better quality product as posible.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say it depends on the semantics of your method.

Will `foo` be almost always found in the list? (for example, if it is a cache that holds a finite amount of objects). If so, then not being found might mean something has gone wrong -- some app initialization failed, for example, or the key is invalid -- and an exception might be justifiable.

In most circumstances, however, I'd return `null`. Maybe the client knows the object might not be there and has coded logic to handle that case; if you used an exception, that code would be much harder to read, understand, and maintain.

Some APIs actually provide two methods: a `find` method that may return null, and a `get` or `load` method that throws an exception.

Hmmm... when in doubt, err in favor of null :)

Comment: +1 for `find`. I prefer that convention, because `find` implies that the item might be missing. `get` on the other hand implies that the caller expects an item to be returned and if it is not there, something is probably wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Returning `null` is fine, if it is documented as a valid result.

Another option is the null-object pattern. That is - an instance of `Foo` that doesn't have any data:

```
public class Foo {
    public static final Foo NULL_FOO = new Foo();
}
```

and return it instead.

Comment: That looks like a great way to hide bugs.

Comment: @Isaac: You mean silent bug as in leaving a catch empty?

Comment: @Bozho: How do use this? Do you simply return a Foo.NULL_FOO in a method?

Comment: Will add that I read something on a blog about a similar pattern being used on .NET with some framework. According to the developer, it turned out to be problematic as they spent a lot of time tracking a bug only to find that the return object was initialized with some default values. So it would probably be a good idea to avoid using default values if you adopt this approach.

Comment: @Isaac Truett it's an option used by many. Null-object pattern it's called. I've used it on some occasions, works perfectly. Just you have to be careful when to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer returning `null`.  This is a perfectly fine result to return from a method, and your code that calls the method should handle null values appropriately.  That might mean throwing an exception in your calling code, but I wouldn't do it in this method.

This way, if someone else wants to call your method down the line, they can handle null values differently than you if they choose.  If you threw and exception it could potentially force another programmer to alter their code in a way different than what they intended.

Of course, there are some cases where it would make sense to throw an exception if something is null (like, a connection object or something like that, that you actually need to have a value and if you don't then that means something is wrong).  But, as a rule of thumb, you should be fine returning null in most cases.

Comment: if it does return `null`, should I document this somewhere in the code? As an additional comment, perhaps?

Comment: You could if you feel like it could be a point of confusion later on.  I think you should always expect that a method could return a null value and handle it in your code appropriately.

Comment: You should mention it in the `@return` part of the Javadoc.

Answer (score 4):

It's best to avoid exceptions if you can, but sometimes you just can't. In this case, what if you had stored `null` in the list? You can't tell the difference between 'found null' and 'could not find what you wanted'.

There is a pattern, it's called [Option Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) and it's used a lot in Scala. You either return a container with the item, or a container of a class that says 'I'm empty'. The wiki article will give a better picture.

You could also have a 'does this exist in the collection?' method which returns a bool, then throw an exception from the above code for if you didn't check first.

---

And just a comment completely unrelated to your actual question. If you implement equals, it should only return true if the two objects are actually considered equal. Therefore the above code must always return the object you pass into it!

Comment: I just thought I'd mention it. I knew it had nothing to do with your actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Best pactice would be to say in the Javadoc that `null` is return when no match is found.

Another approach might be to return a List of matches which could be empty (and could have more than one)  However I don't like this approach.

Another approach might be to return a NULL_FOO of type Foo value.

I would prefer to just return null.

One way around this is to look at what are you going to do with the value and enrich the function so that the returned value is used in the method and not returned. e.g. if you are going to call a method with the value, just call it in the function which avoids the need to return anything.

Comment: The NULL_FOO of type Foo is the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I didn't find guava's [Optional](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class mentioned here and also JDK's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) (from Java 8) which serves the same purpose and has more functionality.

[This article](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) is a good overview on the reasons for using guava's Optional. I highly recommend reading it.

Here's an excerpt:

> What's the point?
>
> Besides the increase in readability that comes from giving null a
>   name, the biggest advantage of Optional is its idiot-proof-ness. It
>   forces you to actively think about the absent case if you want your
>   program to compile at all, since you have to actively unwrap the
>   Optional and address that case. Null makes it disturbingly easy to
>   simply forget things, and though FindBugs helps, we don't think it
>   addresses the issue nearly as well.
>
> This is especially relevant when you're returning values that may or
>   may not be "present." You (and others) are far more likely to forget
>   that other.method(a, b) could return a null value than you're likely
>   to forget that a could be null when you're implementing other.method.
>   Returning Optional makes it impossible for callers to forget that
>   case, since they have to unwrap the object themselves for their code
>   to compile.

My personal opinion, if that matters at all, is that returning null is not so terrible in an already verbose language like Java. The signature of the method sometimes screams that there can be some sort of null kind of result and using Optional doesn't add anything in terms of semantics anyway. For example:

```
public Point2D intersect(Line line)
```

Or in a method that looks up a value in a map by key.

If one calls such a method and performs a null check on the result, it's pretty obvious what is going on (checking for parallel lines or key not found). I would favor returning null lest I bloat my code.

I would always document it in the javadoc though.

Answer (score 1):

majory it depends on the scenarios. If your app is itself producer and consumer of this method then it is completly upto you to decide what to do, Else you need to decide based on usage of the method and Client needs.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `null` is perfectly acceptable. I would go the extra couple dozen keystrokes and document the possibility of returning `null` in the JavaDoc.

Throwing checked exception means you have to try/catch or re-throw that exception everywhere your method gets called. An unchecked exception, especially anything other than an NPE, is going to catch people by surprise.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you're defining an accessor, it should return null. If it were another method where this method should guarantee a non-null response, an exception would be more appropriate.

As a side note though, rather than calling the sample method a getter it might be more appropriate to name it something like `Foo findFoo(Foo f)` since you're searching rather than just getting.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a matter of taste and in this case it also depends on if the list may contain null values. If the list may contain null values, null would also be a valid method argument and you would need to distinguish between returning null (e.g. null was passed, found and returned) or telling the method caller that the passed null value was *not* found.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question directly but it comes from a few remarks I've gotten from Stackoverflow members on similar topics.

> Instead of returning null when foo is not found, should I throw an exception? Does it matter, and is there a "best practices" idiom on the subject? By the way, I know my example is a bit contrived, but I hope you get the idea..."

From what I gather, Exceptions should be thrown from a method when the Exception concerns a parameter given to the method. For example, a method accepting File instances would throw a NullPointerException or an IOException. This is following the idea that there's a contract between the caller and callee that the caller should sent valid objects and take care of them if they're invalid.

Also, you need to decide whether to handle pre- and postconditions. You can place a guard at the beginning of a method to handle parameters and this would save quite a bit of code. However, some view this as an incorrect approach in that some validation, say in a UI, should be done beforehand.

To finish off, it's perfectly valid to return a null object if the intent is to retrieve a a single instance. This is to paraphrase that an object was not found or doesn't exist. When it comes to groups of objects I think the convention is simply to return an empty Collection/List.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on your app and how the method will be used.

1. If you expect a "not found" result happen frequently enough that it could negatively affect performance*, then return null, and check for it in the caller.
2. If "not found" results will be relatively rare or will cause you app give up on the request, then throwing an exception would be fine.  Exceptions could make your code easier to read, as you can then guarantee a successful return will produce an object, so you don't have to null-check it.

I subscribe to the opinion that exceptions should be used for exceptional conditions, which is a superset of error conditions.  I also have adopted Spring/Hibernate's preference for unchecked exceptions, which avoids burdensome try/catch logic.

* There is not much performance overhead from using exceptions vs. returning null.  I just did a quick test, it takes 4ms to call a method a million times that returns null, and only 535ms to another method million times that throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view I haven't read in the other answers is the following:

Does the `list` contain `null`'s of `Foo`? If this is the case, one would not know whether the id was found, or whether it was associated with `null`. In this case:

- Throw an exception that the list is not found;
- Wrap the result in another object (e.g. a `SearchResult`, which tells you if the object was found, it's associative id, it's result, or no result if it was not found);
- Create the method `existsFoo(int id)`.

Each solution has it's own problems, and it depends on the case which to use:

- As others noted, `Exception`s are *exceptional*;
- A wrapper, `SearchResult`, has to be allocated each time you'd like to retry a search. The wrapper can be made *mutable*, but this introduces a lot of new difficulties and problems;
- `existsFoo` has to search the list which doubles the cost of knowing whether the key exists or not.

Generally I can say:

- Is an ID *not being found* exceptional? Use `IllegalArgumentException`;
- Is the result passed to other classes, used as an object? Use a wrapper, e.g. `SearchResult`;
- Is with `getFoo` only checked whether it's null or not (it exists or not)? Use another method, `existsFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that coding for null is simple and easy boilerplate programmer conditioning, it adds little value for the complexity introduced. Always assuming non-null references makes for cleaner logic with slightly less code -- you still have to test for failure.

The annotation [excerpt below](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UseNullable) will help you to not fall into the old ways...

> **Use @Nullable**
>
> To eliminate `NullPointerExceptions` in your codebase, you must be
>   disciplined about null references. We've been successful at this by
>   following and enforcing a simple rule:
>
> *Every parameter is non-null unless explicitly specified.*
>
> The Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java and JSR-305 have simple APIs
>   to get a nulls under control. Preconditions.checkNotNull can be used
>   to fast-fail if a null reference is found, and `@Nullable` can be used
>   to annotate a parameter that permits the null value:
>
> ```
> import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;
> import static javax.annotation.Nullable;
>
> public class Person {
>   ...
>
>   public Person(String firstName, String lastName, @Nullable Phone phone) {
>     this.firstName = checkNotNull(firstName, "firstName");
>     this.lastName = checkNotNull(lastName, "lastName");
>     this.phone = phone;
>   }
> ```
>
> If null is permissible by your class, you can annotate the field or
>   parameter with @Nullable ... using any @Nullable annotation, like
>   edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.Nullable or javax.annotation.Nullable.